# How can `org-schedule` jump to calendar window?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

When I apply `org-schedule`, the following minibuffer shows up:

[image]

where the cursor is on the `SCHEDULED Date+time [2022-03-12]: ...`. Here I type `o` or `.` but nothing happens, or I cannot use arrows in the calendar. Hence I have to apply `other-window` two times to jump into the calendar window and move around using arrows.

Instead could I jump into the  calendar window right away, where I can select the numbers and press `RET`?

Comment: Ah yes sir I meant `calendar window`

Comment: If you are using a mouse, you can click with the left mouse button on a date directly. Are you looking for a keyboard-only solution?

Comment: Ah I don't use mouse, I mean I can't in the terminal :-( Yes I was looking for a keyboard-only solution

Comment: Have you looked into the existing API for choosing dates?  It is way more efficient than navigating to dates with arrow keys.  Check section 8.2.1 of the `org` manual.

Comment: Yeah but to use arrow keys first I had to apply two times `C-o` (`other-window`) to switch into calender window, which I wanted to jump into calender window right away to use arrow keys

Comment: @alper That is not what @FranBurstall meant. Really, you don't need to go to the other window. Things like `+1d`, `wed` are just faster and more convenient.

Comment: @alper But, if you just want the calendar, you could use `windmove-up` so that you can jump straight to the calendar window, instead of `other-window` twice.

Comment: @gusbrs Thanks I got it now. I just need to bind a keybinding for `windmove-up`

Comment: Arrows should work out-of-the-box even when you're in the modeline, **not** in the Calendar buffer. From your theme, you're not using Vanilla emacs. Try with `emacs -Q`, set mode to `org-mode`, add a header, and type `C-c C-s` to schedule something. Arrows should work. If they do, then start debugging your non-vanilla config.

Comment: Hm I always use `C-p C-n` for arrows and never use normal arrow keys. Arrow keys apply : `> [Beginning of history; no preceding item]` like I said its in the `SCHEDULED Date+time [2022-03-14]:` so arrows keys does not apply into calender window section I need to jump into that

Comment: @mankoff Ah shift arrow keys work! But `shift-C-p` or `shift-C-n` did not help

Comment: Correct. Shift-arrow, or `next tue` or `thu` or `03-15` or `++7w` or `.+7w` or `+7w` all act as different shortcuts.

Comment: @mankoff can we bind Shift-arrows to `shift-C-p` and `shift-C-n`?